# How to copy file from local system to ftp server using Batch file- Task Scheduler

Tags: batch-file, scheduler

I need to copy files from local system to ftp server.
I require batch file which I will use to schedule the task in windows scheduler.
please provide if example.
I am able to schedule the task on the local system.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

```
rsync -r folder/ user@server.com:/location_on_server
```

Windows equivalent can be found [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145(v=ws.10).aspx)

Comment: where do I specify credentials ??

Comment: sorry my bad.. you need to do ssh key pair with the server so no password is required. if you want to put this in a batch script it's not a good tactic to hard code credentials